# How can I get R to read these cells as blank instead of NA?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
column1,column2,column3
data,,
more data,data,
```

I read it using

```
read.csv("file.csv")
```

And I get

```
> read.csv("file.csv")
    column1 column2 column3
1      data              NA
2 more data    data      NA
```

Is it possible to get R to read the data in column3 as empty cells, just as it does with the empty cell in column2?

Comment: Well  look what's happening there, the second column is getting what you want (I think).  But you don't actually have a comma indicating the third column.  So probably that is what you want to do, make an empty column in the place the csv is coming from.  I'm assuming you have some rows eventually that have three columns of data and are not trying to read in a completely blank column, is that right?

Comment: `read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = "character")`. Explanation is in `?read.csv`, argument `na.strings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help('read.csv')`, section **Arguments**, my emphasis:

> na.strings
>   a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted
>   as NA values. Blank fields are also considered to be **missing values in
>   logical, integer, numeric and complex fields**. Note that the test
>   happens after white space is stripped from the input, so na.strings
>   values may need their own white space stripped in advance.

The above highlighted part does not refer to `"character"` class. So define the column of interest to be of class `"character"`.

In the question's case, all 3 columns are of the same class and since argument `colClasses` recycles its value, the following is enough.

```
read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = "character")
#    column1 column2 column3
#1      data                
#2 more data    data
```